# Filtering name with two condition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

I have a sample list of student and grades/subject in this file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxzSF.png)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NeHlUaRnbvdJ2yJ38fUETGgBoYseQ8CuXmwRCwObAlM/edit#gid=0

On the range A16:A I'd like to see the list of names who has the grades of around 90-100 when I check any of the checkbox on B15:k15

the first example is when I check all of the boxes

I will only see the first name on the list because he is the only one with the 90-100 scores on all subject

2nd example when I check B15 and C15

I will only see the 1st and 2nd names on the list because he's those who only able to get a 90-100 score on those two subjects.

Is there a way to do this kind of filtering? thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Since this is your first post, I'm going to go with the approach I think you'll find easiest to understand. It's a long formula (which I've placed in a new sheet called "Erik Help" in A16), but it's just a repeat of the same element several times:

```
=FILTER(A2:K11, IF(B15=TRUE, B2:B11>=90, B2:B11^0), IF(C15=TRUE, C2:C11>=90, B2:B11^0), IF(D15=TRUE, D2:D11>=90, D2:D11^0), IF(E15=TRUE, E2:E11>=90, E2:E11^0), IF(F15=TRUE, F2:F11>=90, F2:F11^0), IF(G15=TRUE, G2:G11>=90, G2:G11^0), IF(H15=TRUE, H2:H11>=90, H2:H11^0), IF(I15=TRUE, I2:I11>=90, I2:I11^0), IF(J15=TRUE, J2:J11>=90, J2:J11^0), IF(K15=TRUE, K2:K11>=90, K2:K11^0))
```

The first argument of FILTER tells the function what to filter (in this case A2:K11).

After that, an IF statement is set up to check each checkbox. If the checkbox is checked, the FILTER will only include students who obtained a 90 or higher in that subject.

If the checkbox is NOT checked, then the student is automatically included (that's the part that says "B2:B11^0" etc., since anything to the zero-power equals 1, and 1 and TRUE are the same to Google Sheets). In other words, if no checkboxes were checked, then all students would read TRUE for all subjects, i.e., all students would be included (or, to think of it another way, no one is rules out). While the ^0 is not strictly necessary (i.e., any number other than zero is the same as TRUE), I think it's better formula practice and easier for others to understand if TRUE is represented either as TRUE or as 1.

I also set conditional formatting on A15:A, to bold the name as you had it. (The conditional formatting rule says, in English, "If anything is there, use bold.") You can see the rule by clicking anywhere in the range A15:A, then selecting **Format > Conditional formatting** from the menu and clicking the open the rule that appears in the window to the right of the screen.